# *-isomorphism of a C*-algebra into an involutive Banach algebra is norm increasing

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

The following is a proposition of Takesaki's Operator theory:

[image]

My question: How does he assume, considering the C*-subalgebra generated by k instead of $*$-Banach algebra B? Are we sure that the C*-algebra generated by k is a C*-subalgebra of B?

Comment: What's the exact definition of "involutive Banach Algebra"? Is there any condition on the involution?

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Every C*-algebra is an involutive Banach algebra (*-Banach algebra)with the condition that $||x^*x||=||x||^2$.

Comment: niki: You did not answer @Martin's question.  From context it appears that for Banach $*$-algebras it is assumed that the involution is isometric.

Comment: @JonasMeyer : What are you meaning by involution is isometric? Involution is just an operation, isn't it?

Comment: @niki: It is assumed (apparently, although you can check in you book which I do not have handy) that $\|x^*\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in B$.  This means that the map $x\mapsto x^*$ is isometric.  This would not follow from the other axioms of being a Banach algebra and also a $*$-algebra, so it is a good idea to be clear on what the assumptions are.

Comment: @JonasMeyer : Yes, you are right. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a typo. It should say the C*-algebra generated by $h$ and the closed $*$-algebra generated by $k$, or equivalent.  There is no assumptions that $k$ sits in a C*-algebra.   For instance, later it is noted that $\|k\|\geq \|k\|_{\mathrm{sp}}$, but this would be equality if it were in a C*-algebra.